# Names of finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, big-list, soft-question, terminology

> Question: If you have a finite group, how do you name it?

If, for whatever reason, you have to list all subgroups of $GL_2({\mathbb F}_5)$ up to isomorphism in a paper, you are likely to write something along the lines of

$$
C_1, C_2, C_2, C_3, 
C_{2,2}, C_4,
C_5, 
C_6, S_3,  
Q_8, C_8, C_{2,4}, D_4, 
$$
$$
C_{10}, D_5,
D_6, C_{12}, C_3\rtimes C_4, 
C_{2,4}\rtimes C_2, OMC_{16}, C_{4,4}, 
$$
$$
C_{20}, D_{10}, G_{20}, C_5\rtimes C_4,
SL_2(F_3), C_4\times S_3, C_3\rtimes C_8, C_{24}, 
$$
$$
Q_8\rtimes C_4,
C_2\times G_{20}, C_2\times G_{20}, C_4\times D_5, 
(C_{2,4}\rtimes C_2)\rtimes C_3, C_3\rtimes OMC_{16}, 
$$
$$
C_4\times G_{20}, C_2.A_5, 
SL_2(F_3)\rtimes C_4, 
(C_2.A_5)\rtimes C_2,
GL_2(F_5).
$$

Computer algebra packages tend to produce a human-unfriendly output of 
generators and relations or generating permutations in $S_n$. How do 
**you** convert from one to the other and decide how to name complicated groups? 
I am looking for standard names, standard constructions, conventions and 
notations. For me a good notation is informative, 
human friendly, short and is generally as close as possible to what you would 
use in a paper. I am also looking for any kind of canonical conventions: e.g. $(C_5\times C_5)\rtimes C_4$ or $(C_5\rtimes C_4)\times C_5$?

---

(The reason I am asking is that I seem to have to work with funny groups all 
the time recently. I have a Magma function for personal use that analyzes and 
names finite groups; e.g. it produces the list 
above for $GL_2({\mathbb F}_5)$, and I personally find this really useful.

Currently it knows various standard groups: cyclic, abelian, dihedral, 
alternating, symmetric, special $p$-groups (semi-dihedral, generalized 
quaternion, "other maximal cyclic", Heisenberg), simple groups, linear groups (SL, GL, O, 
SP) and eventually their projective versions; it tries to recognize 
direct, semidirect (and eventually wreath) products if the group is not too 
large, and reverts to chief series if everything else fails.

Recently sufficiently many people asked me to share the code that I'll make 
it public domain. But before that I'd very much like to get suggestions from the MO 
community how to make it as useful as possible for most people.)

---

**Edit (6 years later)**: The names are finally in public domain ([groupnames.org](http://groupnames.org)), and comments and suggestions are still very much welcome.

Comment: What is $G_{20}$?

Comment: $C_5\rtimes C_4$ with faithful action, I know that some people call it $G_{20}$ but I don't know to which extent this is a standard notation

Comment: $G_{20}$? I'd call it $F_{20}$ as it is the Frobenius group of order $20$. So good luck with finding names!

Comment: I've not heard of that notation, but I am not that much of a finite group theorist (I've never had to use the ATLAS, for one thing). I assumed that was what you meant by $C_5\rtimes C_4$, but that makes sense. Is $OMC_{16}$ what some people would call the modular group of order $16$? I think notation in this area is highly non-standardised: even the notation of the dihedral groups are not standard!

Comment: Jonathan, I thought the notation for the dihedral groups is standard: group theorists write the dihedral group of order 2n as D_{2n} and everyone else (?) writes the group as D_n.  

Comment: @KConrad: I suppose I'll have an option IAmAGroupTheorist:boolean in my code to deal with dihedral groups then. @Jonathan: My OMC16 comes from the last paragraph of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasidihedral_group, I don't know if that's the same as a modular group. What is the modular group of order 16 (as generators and relations or whatever)?

Comment: About your example to canonical conventions: $(C_5 \rtimes C_4)\times C_5$ leaves only two options (assuming it's not a direct product): faithful action of $C_4$ or not. As $(C_5 \times C_5)\rtimes C_4$ allows also the action of $C_4$ to be fixed point free, new possibilities arise, and it is more ambiguous, and hence worse.

Comment: I just made up "other-maximal-cyclic" since it had no given name in Gorenstein or Huppert.  When it has order 16, it is also called the modular group (it being rare amongst groups of order 16 to have a modular subgroup lattice), but the article is about the infinite family.

Comment: In particular, for order 32 there are three groups with modular subgroup lattices but in which normality is not transitive; one of these is an o-m-c, but the other two are not.  The name is only used for order 16, and I think only because it gives a name to one of the groups without an otherwise descriptive name.

Comment: @Tim: If you are interested, email me about some of the pitfalls of such a function.  We've had several years of experience with providing such a function to users, and have discovered some non-obvious issues (that are a hassle to type in this interface).

Comment: Unfortunately, we all still publish paper in Dead Tree.  If you use a more modern graphical user interface, namely Light Emitting Diode, then you can usually provide greater functionality to your readers: allow them to click or double click or right click or whatever on each name for more information on it.  (Such hyperlinking is also available in Dead Tree, of course, in the form of footnotes, endnotes, appendices, and references.)

Comment: Have you looked into what the GAP function StructureDescription currently does? Details can be found in the manual: http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/htm/ref/CHAP037.htm#SECT006


Comment: @Nick, Jack & Theo: Thank you, that's helpful!

Comment: Noah Snyder has suggested the notation $D_{2 \cdot n}$, as an unambiguous compromise for dihedral groups.

Answer (score 6):

It is difficult to come up with a consistent notation for all groups of a certain order since their construction is somewhat chaotic.  We might be able to describe all the groups of order $p^3$ or $p^4$ but what about all groups of order $p^6$?  Or order $p^4q^2$?

The software package GAP (http://www.gap-system.org/) has a catalogue of all groups of order up to 2000 or so and so I've sometimes referred to groups by their catalogue number, for example, SmallGroup(96, 33) refers to a particular group in that library.  (As does SmallGroup(512, 1000000)!)

Comment: I agree, one might use the small group database if there is really no other choice, but generally this is not very human friendly. E.g. SmallGroup(96,33) is $C_3\rtimes D_{16}$, which may not describe it uniquely but at least it says more. 

Comment: In GAP you can try StructureDescription:

gap> StructureDescription(SmallGroup(96,33));
"(C3 x D16) : C2"

Answer (score 6):

For transitive permutation groups the first paper in Journal of Computation & Mathematics
by Conway, Hulpke, & McKay lists the smaller degrees with "respectable names".

Answer (score 4):

There is a useful convention to decorate some of the groups with an index which is the smallest $n$ for which the group can act transitively on $n$ points, i.e. embeds in $S_n$ as a transitive subgroup. The notation for $S_n, A_n, D_n, C_n$, your $Q_8$ and for example Mathieu groups $M_{11}, M_{12}, M_{22}$ (although not other sporadic simple groups) follow this pattern.

Of course, there is also another convention to use the size of the group instead...

Comment: ... and, as mathematicians would put it, "This problem is a natural generalization of the dihedral case"

Comment: It's not clear to me that n is the smallest index k for which D_n embeds into S_k.

Comment: That's right, $D_{15}$ can act faithfully on $3+5=8$ points. Smallest $n$ for which $G$ is a *transitive* subgroup of $S_n$?